# Synapse formation

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, literature, synapses

I am trying to learn about neuronal synapse formation, but the literature is intimidating to someone with little background knowledge.  I am interested in synapse formation in both human adults as well as during human development.  Could someone point me to a good paper or review that provides the necessary introductory information?  I am a highly technical individual, but have little more than a 1 year introductory neuroscience course at the undergraduate level.

EDIT:

I'm interested in the formation of structure in small-scale systems (100's to 1000's of cells) of neurons, so I imagine that would require a combination of cell-based and neurophysiological knowledge.

Comment: Welcome to Bio. What do you wish to know, I mean what is the area of expertise? Molecular Bio (Cell signalling), morphology (cellular level) or neurophysiology (communication)? There is a lot of stuff out there. Finding literature mainly means knowing what you *don't* need.

Comment: Alright, to be honest this question is definitely too broad to answer. Even the formation of small structures is a HUGE (and I mean huge) field of study that doesn't just span neurons. I will tell you how you can find such papers and the ones you are looking for are specifically called "Reviews". A review article basically rounds up (usually a hundred or so) articles to form a consensus about what the prevailing thoughts on a specific topic are when looking at the research done by the scientific community of course. If you want to learn about neuron development I suggest you use a scholarly se